# Sequelize joins using model query , DB is postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have two tables "Table 1" and "Table 2". I am using nodejs and DB is postgres

Table 1

```
| id       | createdOn                 |
| -------- | --------------------------|
| 1        | 2023-08-04T14:48:54+00:00 |
| 2        | 2023-08-04T14:48:54+00:00 |
```

Table 2

```
| logId    | createdOn                 | statusID | id |
| -------- | --------------------------|----------|----|
| 1        | 2023-08-04T14:48:54+00:00 | 1        |1   |
| 2        | 2023-08-04T14:48:54+00:00 | 2        |1   |
| 3        | 2023-08-04T14:48:54+00:00 | 1        |2   |
| 4        | 2023-08-04T14:48:54+00:00 | 1        |1   |
| 5        | 2023-08-04T14:48:54+00:00 | 2        |2   |
| 6        | 2023-08-04T14:48:54+00:00 | 3        |2   |
| 7        | 2023-08-04T14:48:54+00:00 | 3        |1   |
| 8        | 2023-08-04T14:48:54+00:00 | 4        |2   |
```

id in Table 2 is foreign key.

I need to use only sequelize model query to fetch all columns from Table 1 and only statusID column from Table 2 where the logId is max for the id (i.e most recently updated status).

I have used subquery as literal where I have done order by logID desc limit 1. But is there any way where I dont use subquery. Also when I use MAX function in subquery, it gives me all the statusID in desc order, it doesn't give single result.

using logID desc limit 1 will affect the perfomance? Please suggest the best way to do this.

Also if I dont use subquery, I get statusID inside another object.
for example :

```
    {
     id: 1,
    createdOn: 2023-08-04T14:48:54+00:00,
    Table2: {
    statusID : 3
    }
    }
```

Can I get statusID in same heirarchy as other two columns as id, createdOn?

Also if possible, can I get the createdOn field as UNIX timestamp i.e in miliseconds?

Currently I am using this query

```
    await model.table1.findAll({ include: { model: model.table2, required: true, order: [['logId', 'DESC']], limit: 1, attributes: ['statusID', 'status'] } });
```

Comment: Is there a reason why `id` is flapping around in the column like that?

Comment: For what it's worth, having `id` mean "primary key" in one table and "totally not that, actually a foreign key to some other unspecified thing" in another is *really annoying* to anyone using this schema.

Comment: its not properly formatted I guess

Comment: I was worried it's a string value with padding being irregular.

Comment: Its done to keep log of every status change of id from table 1. Better way to keep track of such logs can be suggested